# Stored Functions

Tags: mysql, arguments, stored-functions

I have an issue where I'm trying to make a stored function to search for a user's username and password. The arguments to the function should be the username and password and it must return true if the username and password combo exist and false if it doesn't. This is what I've created so far with no success:

```
 delimiter $$
    create function cred(u varchar(15), p varchar(6))
        returns char(5) 
        begin
            declare a CHAR(5);
            if (select username = u and pwd = p from customers) then set a = 'true';
            else set a = 'false';
            end if;
        end$$
delimiter ;

select cred('dJete', 'abc112');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use return-statement in function to return the value. Also, minor fixes to the actual query where you match the customer:

```
create function cred(in_username varchar(15), in_password varchar(6))
returns char(5) 
begin

declare v_cnt int;

select count(*) into v_cnt
from customers
where username = in_username and pwd = in_password;

if (v_cnt>0) then
  return 'true';
else
  return 'false';
end if;

end
$$
```